# In akka cluster sharding, how to detect existence of a sharding typekey?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

As akka docs described, akka send messages fire-and-forget.

But in ask pattern, if a typekey not exists, I still need waiting for response util timeout.
Is there an approach to failure immediately on sending message to non-existing typekey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By non-existing type key, I presume you mean a typekey which hasn't been passed to `init`.

If using typed sharding, you can ask the local `ActorRef` returned from `ClusterSharding(actorSystem).shardState` with the `GetShardRegionState(typeKey, _)` query.  The response `CurrentShardRegionState`'s `shards` will be empty if the typekey hasn't been initialized (note that since this relies on classic cluster sharding under the hood, this will technically only verify that there's a typekey with that name initialized) on this node.

In classic sharding, the set of typekey names which have been initialized on the node can be obtained synchronously via `ClusterSharding(actorSystem).shardTypeNames`.

Note that it is generally recommended to initialize sharding for all type keys very early in the startup process and to sequence the startup such that functionality which depends on sharding is not started until all the type keys have been initialized.  For example, one can trigger sharding initialization on cluster formation and then (in the same callback) start serving HTTP requests or consuming from a message broker.  If one is running in Kubernetes, one can bind HTTP immediately, but define a readiness check which doesn't turn green until the sharding typekeys have been initialized: k8s will then not send HTTP traffic to the instance until sharding is ready.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What if a wrong typekey , for example, a http server forward all http request to entity calls, the type keys come from user input. 
And the `GetShardRegionState ` only return shards on current node, but current node's role doesn't spawn entity for the typekey, so the query returned nothing.

Comment: If you can't be sure that the typekey is initialized, call `init` on it.  Cluster Sharing isn't really intended for that hyperdynamic use case.

Comment: There is the `GetClusterShardingStats` command, which is cluster-wide for a typekey (conditioned upon it being `init`d locally (it will respond with an empty `Map` if not).